# Is it possible to write a web crawler in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want the following functions and I know about the client side domain restriction in javascript however I don't know if this restrictions applies to what I want the crawler to do.

1. Javascript to load the text content of a given website's url address to a div or assign it to a var.
2. the tags should then be parsed from the text.

3 the body of text should be searched for a specific word. If the word is found it should take the neighbouring sentence including the word and display it on the alert message.

I am writing a firefox application so everthing must be done on client side.

Comment: Is this for a Firefox plugin or for a website?

Comment: You just answered your own question.

Comment: Its firefox extensions which retrieves link address when the user hovers over links on any given page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and easiest thing you can do is:

- make a dynamic page on your server that accepts a param: example page.php?url=
- your javascript will AJAX that page with the url it needs so it can retrive the HTML (thru your php script) and then parse it in js/client

Comment: I ve got php server installed, I get the url address from my firefox extensions. Is it possible to make a call from the extension to a php script and the php script responds by sending a body of text to the js

Comment: This is completly another question (_Is it possible to make a call from the extension to a php script_). I gave you the base on how to preceed, if you need specific help on firefox exstension or PHP code open another question :) (select this as answer before XD)

Comment: I need urgent help man. I used yboss to search for keywords but it doesn't return good results. I am doing my final year project deadline is in 27th march need to think of another way to implement the behaviour I want so if you know there is a way a php script can be called from your firefox extensions then please do share your knowledge thanks

Comment: sorry man never made a firefox ext neither used yboss. Open another question

Answer (score 3):

As you just said, you cannot use Javascript to retrieve arbitrary content from another domain.

However, you could write a server-side proxy in your own domain which forwards requests to arbitrary URLs and passes along the responses.